# I want to update data in mysql using the get method

Tags: php, mysqli, get

Good morning I am seeking for a help regarding on my php code. I have a problem updating a value in database using get method.

Here is the function I have a form method which is GET and i have a forloop where in inside that loop counts the number of data with the same tracking code now. for example i have a 3 same tracking code so  i have a 3 textbox and also i have a 3 submit button. Now i want to update the textbox 1 and click submit it will automatically updated.

For reference here is my code:

```
enter code here<form method="get" action="view-reservation.php">
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
  <td>January</td>
  <td>February</td>
  <td>March</td>
  <td>April</td>
  <td>May</td>
  <td>June</td>
  <td>July</td>
  <td>August</td>
  <td>September</td>
  <td>October</td>
  <td>November</td>
  <td>December</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($view as $key => $data):?>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="track" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->track?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="pid" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->pid?>">
  <input type="text" name="jan" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->jan?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="feb" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->feb?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="mar" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->mar?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="apr" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->apr?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="may" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->may?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="jun" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->jun?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="jul" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->jul?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="aug" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->aug?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="sep" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->sept?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="oct" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->oct?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="nov" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->nov?>"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="dec" size="1" value="<?php echo $data->dec?>"></td>
  <td>

  <a href="view-reservation.php?track=<?php echo $data->track?>&&pid=<?php echo $data->pid?>&&jan=<?php echo $data->jan?>" 
  class="label label-danger">Update Payment</a></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif?>
</form>
</table>
```

Here is my query when i execute:

```
if(isset($_GET['track']) && isset($_GET['pid']) && isset($_GET['jan']))
{
//
$jan = filter($_GET['jan']);
$track = filter($_GET['track']);
$pid = filter($_GET['pid']);
$query = $con->query("update payment set jan = '500' where track = '$track' and pid='$pid'") or die(mysqli_errno());
if($query)
{
  echo'updated';
}
}
```

Comment: and the problem is ?

Comment: @Dagon There is none; didn't you see? *They want...*

Comment: `filter()` is that some fancy function? [*filter function doesn't exist. Closest matches:*](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=filter+function&scope=quickref)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Hi fred no error appeared it just say updated lick what I echoed on my query. but if i look into the database it is not updated.

Comment: `<?php foreach ($view as $key => $data):?>` where is that taking its values from? Is anything showing in there now when using it?

Comment: This `&&pid=<?php echo $data->pid?>&&jan=<?php echo $data->jan?>"` you're using 2x `&&` it should be only one. `&pid=<?php echo $data->pid?>&jan=<?php echo $data->jan?>"`

Comment: Yes, I created a function that will select * the data when the tracking numbers are the same and it shows on my result the problem is when i click the submit the update query do not execute.

Comment: [Reload this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337718/i-want-to-update-data-in-mysql-using-the-get-method#comment46863855_29337718) if you didn't read it yet.

Comment: what i observe is when i click the submit query for each row it appears the current value of my field not the one i Inputted so meaning if the field name (jan) on the database is 0 and i enter 500 the URL will read it like this one pid=1&jan=0 it should be pid=1&jan=500 so that it will update. can you help me for this one bro.

Comment: No problem is not solve sir